# Communication between React app and a React app inside iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, single-page-application, web-component

I have a React.js SPA (call it A) in part of which I have an iframe with another React.js SPA (call it B). The B SPA gets some of its information from the server and may keep it either in store or state. Is there any possibility of accessing the SPA B store/state via SPA A? Sending a some kind of event of data fetch completion from B to A with a JSON content? I've heard that it's probably possible with Web Components events, but is it possible with React?

Comment: A same origin iframe can communicate more or less freely with its parent. What have you tried?

Comment: I have seen the solution presented in the link below, where I explicitly declare window.parent.postMessage and a listener. Unfortunately I don't find this very satisfying and elegant because it implies (as far as I understand) that the iframe SPA is indeed in an iframe and it has a parent. I'm looking for a more general solution, which would be maybe leaning more towards micro front end pattern by design. https://medium.com/@ariel.salem1989/communicating-with-iframes-712fdc2b4d14